# Xamarin.Forms: How to search in ListView whether Lowercase or Uppercase?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Good Day. I'm creating a SearchBar in Xamarin.Forms (Portable). I was able to do search on my ListView but only in Uppercase. Everytime I search using Lowercase, nothing appears. How can I do searching whether I use Lowercase or Uppercase?

I heard about using ToLower() but I don't know where should I actually put that.  Here's my code.

```csharp
private void Filter()
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_keyword)) 
    {
        EmployeesList = _searchedEmployeesList;
    }
    else
    {
        EmployeesList = _searchedEmployeesList
            .Where(r => r.EMPLOYEE_NAME.Contains(_keyword)).ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you want a completely case-insensitive matching, and saving a few `.ToLower(_keyword)` calls in the LINQ-generated code:

```
var lowerKeyword = _keyword.ToLower(); 
EmployeesList = _searchedEmployeesList
    .Where(r => r.EMPLOYEE_NAME.ToLower().Contains(lowerKeyword)).ToList();
```

Comment: Agree with Mark. Keep in mind, that depending on the size of the data source you might want to either do `.ToLower()` once or use RegEx to save some string allocations